# Ansible show correct result with conditionnal in when from list in dict

Tags: data-structures, ansible, conditional-statements

How i can select the correct "IP" from ping in with_items

Ansible main.yml code:

```
IP_server:
  - north:
      192.168.1.1
      192.168.1.2

- name: Ping command
  shell:
    cmd: "ping -c -w 2 {{ item }}"
  register: "server_ok"
  ignore_errors: yes
  with_items:
    - "{{ IP_server.north }}"
  loop_control:
   loop_var: "correct_server"

- name: "Selected IP"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ IP_server.north.msg }}"
  when: IP_server.north.msg.0.rc == 0
```

Result: Always show first IP: 192.168.1.1

---

Desired result: The correct IP selected by the conditional "....rc==0" in the "when".

---

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are too many errors: 1) ``IP_server.north`` doesn't exist. ``IP_server`` is a list, not a dictionary. 2) ``north`` is a dictionary, not a list. 3) Don't use ``item`` when you changed ``loop_var: "correct_server"`` 4) debug ... See the working example in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    IP_server:
      - 10.1.0.61
      - 10.1.0.62
      - 10.1.0.99
  tasks:
    - command: "ping -c 1 {{ item }}"
      register: server_ok
      ignore_errors: yes
      loop: "{{ IP_server }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ server_ok.results|
                 selectattr('rc', 'eq', 0)|
                 map(attribute='item')|
                 list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************

TASK [command] ******************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=10.1.0.61)
changed: [localhost] => (item=10.1.0.62)
failed: [localhost] (item=10.1.0.99) => changed=true 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  cmd:
  - ping
  - -c
  - '1'
  - 10.1.0.99
  delta: '0:00:03.078826'
  end: '2021-02-25 10:50:17.192211'
  item: 10.1.0.99
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2021-02-25 10:50:14.113385'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: |-
    PING 10.1.0.99 (10.1.0.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 10.1.0.27 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
  
    --- 10.1.0.99 ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - 10.1.0.61
  - 10.1.0.62
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks a lot! How you can register only one result with rc==0 even if two have a rc==0?

Comment: I created other question, I think I erase this is ok for you??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66371588/get-data-from-ping-output-in-ansible

Comment: What is "item" in this line " map(attribute='item')|" ?